# Plotly: Share x-axis for subset of subplots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, subplot

The following python code will share the x-axis for all three subplots:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    vertical_spacing=0.02)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]),
              row=3, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[100, 110, 120]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[1000, 1100, 1200]),
              row=1, col=1)
```

Is there a simple way to share the x-axis on the first two rows, but allow the x-axis of the third row to be set freely?

I'm aware that it's possible to individually specify the ranges via calls to update_xaxis for the individual subplots.  Was wondering if there was another approach that would avoid this: something in the spirit of what @Ali Taghipour Heidari suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Update layout of independent axes with `{"matches": None}`. And layout of dependent axes with `{"matches": "x"}` or whatever axis you want it to match.
For some strange reason you should use "x" instead of "xaxis", "x2" instead of "xaxis2", etc.

```py
# tested with plotly==5.18.0
fig.update_layout(
    {
        "xaxis": {"matches": None},
        "xaxis2": {"matches": "x", "showticklabels": True},
        "xaxis3": {"matches": None},
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by setting shared_xaxes to [True, True, False], The x-axis of the first and second rows will be shared, while the x-axis of the third row will not be shared with the other rows.

```
shared_xaxes=[True, True, False],
```

Comment: For plotly 5.13.1, I get the following error when trying your approach:  ```ValueError: 
The shared_xaxes argument to make_subplots must be one of: [None, True, False, 'rows', 'columns', 'all']
    Received value of type <class 'list'>: [True, True, False]```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is to set the x-axis of two graphs in a subplot to be common and the rest of the graphs to have a different range, then unset the x-axis sharing setting, set the range you want to be common for the two graphs, and hide the x-axis tick marks.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1,
                    #shared_xaxes=True,
                    vertical_spacing=0.02)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]),
              row=3, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[100, 110, 120]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[1000, 1100, 1200]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.update_xaxes(range=[0,5], showticklabels=False, row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0,5], showticklabels=False, row=2, col=1)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This approach (manually specifying the ranges) was the first thing that came to mind.  I was wondering if there was an approach that would avoid that.  Question updated to reflect this desire.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current version does not implement such a feature. Please request additional functionality on [github](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py). There is also a plotly [community](https://community.plotly.com/), so you can ask similar questions there.